# email created by CSS and HTML doesn't work on gmail app [iOS]

Tags: html, css, email

I've create this email by using html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      .button {
        background-color: #8d312f;
      }

      div.title {
        text-align: center;
      }

      div.title2 {
        text-align: center;
      }

      div.buttonDiv {
        text-align: center;
      }

      div.bottomBanner {
        font-family: "Accuratist";
        font-size: 14px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 30px;
      }

      img.logoImg {
        width: 50px;
        height: 58px;
        content: url("finixLogo.png");
      }

    </style>

    <div class="title">
      <h1>Welcom to WOW!</h1>
    </div>
  </head>
    <body style="font-family:Accuratist">

      <div class="title2">
        <h4>To confirm your account click on the following link.</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="buttonDiv">
        <a href="" class="button"> Confirm account </a>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomBanner">
        If you have any questions, contact us:<a href="mailto:email@example.com"> email@example.com </a> <br><br>
      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

But when I try to open a link of the button in gmail app on iphone, it doesn't work instead in apple mail, on ios, it works.
How can I solve the problem?
here's a screenshot of gmail.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7djS.png)

Comment: Different mail systems are like browsers they all work differently and wont all look the same. They are harder to make everything look the same in than browsers. Some of them you are lucky if they use parts of CSS2.

Comment: Here is a CSS support list for some of the different email rendering tools - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I understood, but, for example, how amazon create its emails to be able with each email's systems?

Comment: They use a table layout and dont use modern CSS. They may still use `<font>` tag rather than `<p>`. As the `<p>` can be treated differently in each email tool.

Comment: Also they will probably use something like - https://www.emailonacid.com/ - to test there emails before sending

Comment: You need to use tables if you're building HTML emails. CSS support is not only sketchy, it's rubbish. Campaignmonitor and emailonacid (as 2 others have already mentioned) are extremely helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align: center;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h1>Welcom to WOW!</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p><strong>To confirm your account click on the following link.</strong></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:10px 0 10px;"><a href="#" style="background-color: #8d312f; color: #fff; padding: 10px 20px; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 20px; ">Confirm account</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Confirm account:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">email@example.com </a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very useful.  What did you do? Why?